# Moving element id from front of class to back

Tags: jquery, html

On a button click I am trying to move the front element (image-1) of (my-images class) to the back of the class then shift up the elements. So far this is what I have but it is not doing much. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div class="elegant">
  <button class="button" onclick="leftFunction()">Button</button>
  <div class="my-image" id="image-1">
    <div class="banner">
      <h1 class=imageLetters>Blue</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-image" id="image-2">
    <div class="banner">
      <h1 class=imageLetters>Red</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-image" id="image-3">
    <div class="banner">
      <h1 class=imageLetters>Yellow</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
x = 0;
function leftFunction() {
  x++;
  var count = $(".my-image").length;
  if (x > count) {
    x = 0;
  }
  var image = document.getElementById("image-" + x);
  image.style.display = "none";
  $("image-" + x).append($(".my-image"));
  image.style.display = "block";
}
```

CSS

```
.elegant {
  background: #800000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  align-self: center;
}

.banner {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 40px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}

#image-1 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 555px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/949129/pexels-photo-949129.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
  background-size: 1100px 700px;
  background-position: -60px -20px;
  z-index: 4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}
#image-1:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.03);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

#image-2 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 560px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 150px;
  left: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/949129/pexels-photo-949129.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
  background-size: 1100px 700px;
  background-position: -170px -20px;
  z-index: 5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}
#image-2:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.03);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
#image-3 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 565px;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 150px;
  left: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/949129/pexels-photo-949129.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
  background-size: 1100px 700px;
  background-position: -280px -20px;
  z-index: 6;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}
#image-3:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.03);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

Here is the codepen example I made
https://codepen.io/Angatvir/pen/mjxjxd

Comment: Do I correctly understand that you have 3 image divs (image-1, image-2, image-3) and upon clicking the button you want the first one in the list to go to the end of the list (in the DOM tree)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct for now. What my plan is to have a slider of sorts and on click it  have it move through the image divs. I want to move the front image to the back and hide it. I plan on having more image divs that are hidden behind the 3 image divs and once the first click happens I will move that image to the back and hide it and display the next one in line.

Comment: You have 3 divs and they have different width. Can't really see which one is at front or back

Comment: I made them different width's so I was able to see when it moved to the back..Is that wrong to do? Doesn't it just start at image-1 image-2 then image-3 if that's what I declared in the HTML (wouldnt they be children of #my-image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function leftFunction() {
var e = $('.my-image');

e.eq(0).insertAfter( e.eq(e.length - 1) )
}
```

https://codepen.io/vommbat/pen/VBXEOG

code updated (codepen too)

fade out and fade in:

```
function leftFunction() {
var e = $('.my-image');

e.eq(0).animate({
    opacity: 0 
  }, 1000, function() {
     $(this).insertAfter( e.eq(e.length - 1) ).animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 1000) 
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so this is grabbing the class then moving index 0 to the end?

Comment: Didn't know you could use it as an array like that very cool.

Comment: this   move the first element to the end. Added link

Comment: One last thing vomer is there a way to fade it out right before? Not so sharply like it does?

Comment: try something like this:  e.eq(0).insertAfter( e.eq(e.length - 1) ).hide().show("slow");